# undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.*AnActionIMade*) REACT-REDUX

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I call the action using "this.props.UpdateInfo(values);"

I used *connect* from react-redux and implemented it as seen below:

I have seen online to use mapdispatchtoprops but this did not work either. 
when i call it simply using UpdateInfo(values) it works but the return (dispatch) is not called nothing inside is executed.

I also tried this.props.dispatch(UpdateInfo(values) and this did not work either.

As per comment the code is below.

```
 personalinfo.js

 Registration2Submit(values) {
  this.props.UpdateInfo(values);
} me calling the function this is where it errors

 const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
 loading: state.ques.loading,
 };
};

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { UpdateInfo }) 
(RegisterInfo);`
 //my mapping and connecting the action and component. 

myactioncreator.js 

export const UpdateInfo = (Obj) => {
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
console.log('got here 0');
return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('got here 1');
    dispatch({ type: VALIDATING });
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/userinfo`)
        .push(Obj)
  };
 };
 // this is the action. when i run it without the this.props the first 
 console log registers
```

Comment: Please include the shortest relevant section of your code in the body of the question. Screenshots aren't useful because somebody who wants to answer your question can't copy and paste the code to edit it and find out what's wrong, and because other people experiencing your problem can't search for it. There's also quite a lot of code, so you might want to take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I forgot to bind the Registration2Submit. This fixed the error.

```
Registration2Submit = (values) => {
   this.props.UpdateInfo(values);
};
```